# Timer logging issue?

Tags: java, android, timer

I am making an app that has a timer. I want to put a log in the logcat when 10 seconds are up. The timer does a different task at 20 seconds. Here is my attempt:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
public class TwentySeconds extends Service {

MediaPlayer mp;

final String TAG = "MyCountdown";

CountDownTimer cdt;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.v(TAG, "In start command");

     cdt = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long timeRemaining = 20000 - millisUntilFinished;
            if(timeRemaining % 1000 == 0){
                Log.v(TAG, "Time remaining" +(timeRemaining % 1000) + " seconds left");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.v(TAG, "Finished");

            Intent intent = new    Intent(TwentySeconds.this,GameOver.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Log.v(TAG, "About to start activity");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    cdt.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

The logic for the code seems great, but for some reason, it is not displaying. Thanks so much for all of your time, please let me know.

```
{Rich}
```

Comment: you set time remaining on tick? and you print timeRemaining mod 1000 as time remaining? it will always 0

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira  It should be 10, right? 1000 % 1000 = 0?

Comment: Can you please include code rather than screenshotting it? It makes it much more accessible and searchable.

Comment: @ajshort sure here it is:

Comment: @ajshort https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3e7befbccc390a84a82a

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the code, not include it in a screenshot or off-site resource.

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Exactly, I am waiting for the point where 1000 % 1000 = 0, which is ten. Therefor; I am waiting 10 seconds. My question is, why isn't this working?

Comment: @ajshort Okay, I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CountDownTimer is not a 100% precise timer, so you shouldn't attempt to do such a precise calculation, because it will fail 99% of the time.

Maybe just do:

```
millisUntilFinished / 1000
```

as your interval is 1 second.

Try this:

```
 @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          long timeRemaining = 20000 - millisUntilFinished;
          Log.v(TAG, "Time remaining " + (timeRemaining / 1000) + " seconds left");
    }
```

Comment: What should I use then?

Comment: You probably better use some range of values, and not something precise.

Comment: I get: incompatable types: from boolean to long

Comment: if(millisUntilFinished/1000 = 0){
                    Log.v(TAG, "Time remaining" +(timeRemaining % 1000) + " seconds left");
                }

Comment: But this will log it every milliseconds, I only want to log it every ten seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your edit though, but do you know how I can achieve that?

Comment: I will make sure to mark you best answer and like your post once I get it!

Comment: Your CountDownTimer invokes the onTick Method approximately every 1000ms, that is the reaso this should work

Comment: Thanks, I ended up rounding it by adding 500 and dividing by 1000. Anyway, I marked you best answer and liked your post!